# Issue with getting json data

Tags: magento-1.9, php, json

I want to get "`scanDetail`" array's 1st objects 1st element "Scan": Shipment Delivered

> details tracking:{      "Shipment":{
>         "@attributes":{
>            "WaybillNo":"69561350456",
>            "RefNo":"100000718"
>         },
>         "Prodcode":"A",
>         "Service":"Dart Apex - Door To Door",
>         "PickUpDate":"17 August 2017",
>         "PickUpTime":"1944",
>         "Origin":"BANGALORE",
>         "OriginAreaCode":"BLR",
>         "Destination":"GURGAON",
>         "DestinationAreaCode":"GGN",
>         "ProductType":"Non Documents",
>         "SenderName":"FYND",
>         "ToAttention":"Shivani Rathore",
>         "Weight":"2.0",
>         "Status":"SHIPMENT DELIVERED",
>         "StatusType":"DL",
>         "ExpectedDeliveryDate":"19 August 2017",
>         "StatusDate":"18 August 2017",
>         "StatusTime":"15:00",
>         "ReceivedBy":"RHEBA",
>         "Instructions":"Awb# not linked your a/c",
>         "Scans":{
>            "ScanDetail":[
>               {
>                  "Scan":"SHIPMENT DELIVERED",
>                  "ScanCode":"000",
>                  "ScanType":"DL",
>                  "ScanGroupType":"T",
>                  "ScanDate":"18-Aug-2017",
>                  "ScanTime":"15:00",
>                  "ScannedLocation":"LASTMILE E-TAIL DELIVERY",
>                  "ScannedLocationCode":"GLM"
>               },
>               {
>                  "Scan":"SHIPMENT OUT FOR DELIVERY",
>                  "ScanCode":"002",
>                  "ScanType":"UD",
>                  "ScanGroupType":"S",
>                  "ScanDate":"18-Aug-2017",
>                  "ScanTime":"10:41",
>                  "ScannedLocation":"LASTMILE E-TAIL DELIVERY",
>                  "ScannedLocationCode":"GLM"
>               },
>               {
>                  "Scan":"SHIPMENT ARRIVED",
>                  "ScanCode":"001",
>                  "ScanType":"UD",
>                  "ScanGroupType":"S",
>                  "ScanDate":"18-Aug-2017",
>                  "ScanTime":"10:06",
>                  "ScannedLocation":"LASTMILE E-TAIL DELIVERY",
>                  "ScannedLocationCode":"GLM"
>               },
>               {
>                  "Scan":"SHIPMENT FURTHER CONNECTED",
>                  "ScanCode":"003",
>                  "ScanType":"UD",
>                  "ScanGroupType":"S",
>                  "ScanDate":"18-Aug-2017",
>                  "ScanTime":"09:06",
>                  "ScannedLocation":"GGN E-TAIL DELIVERIES",
>                  "ScannedLocationCode":"GED"
>               },
>               {
>                  "Scan":"SHIPMENT REDIRECTED ON SAME AWB",
>                  "ScanCode":"050",
>                  "ScanType":"RD",
>                  "ScanGroupType":"T",
>                  "ScanDate":"18-Aug-2017",
>                  "ScanTime":"08:34",
>                  "ScannedLocation":"GGN E-TAIL DELIVERIES",
>                  "ScannedLocationCode":"GED"
>               },
>               {
>                  "Scan":"WRONG PINCODE, WILL IMPACT DELIVERY",
>                  "ScanCode":"048",
>                  "ScanType":"UD",
>                  "ScanGroupType":"T",
>                  "ScanDate":"18-Aug-2017",
>                  "ScanTime":"08:25",
>                  "ScannedLocation":"GGN E-TAIL DELIVERIES",
>                  "ScannedLocationCode":"GED"
>               },
>               {
>                  "Scan":"SHIPMENT ARRIVED",
>                  "ScanCode":"001",
>                  "ScanType":"UD",
>                  "ScanGroupType":"S",
>                  "ScanDate":"18-Aug-2017",
>                  "ScanTime":"07:56",
>                  "ScannedLocation":"GGN E-TAIL DELIVERIES",
>                  "ScannedLocationCode":"GED"
>               },
>               {
>                  "Scan":"SHIPMENT FURTHER CONNECTED",
>                  "ScanCode":"003",
>                  "ScanType":"UD",
>                  "ScanGroupType":"S",
>                  "ScanDate":"18-Aug-2017",
>                  "ScanTime":"06:42",
>                  "ScannedLocation":"GOPINATH BAZAR HUB",
>                  "ScannedLocationCode":"GNH"
>               },
>               {
>                  "Scan":"SHIPMENT ARRIVED AT HUB",
>                  "ScanCode":"020",
>                  "ScanType":"UD",
>                  "ScanGroupType":"S",
>                  "ScanDate":"17-Aug-2017",
>                  "ScanTime":"22:06",
>                  "ScannedLocation":"BIAL HUB",
>                  "ScannedLocationCode":"BIA"
>               },
>               {
>                  "Scan":"SHIPMENT FURTHER CONNECTED",
>                  "ScanCode":"003",
>                  "ScanType":"UD",
>                  "ScanGroupType":"S",
>                  "ScanDate":"17-Aug-2017",
>                  "ScanTime":"21:47",
>                  "ScannedLocation":"ULSOOR MINI HUB",
>                  "ScannedLocationCode":"UMH"
>               },
>               {
>                  "Scan":"SHIPMENT PICKED UP",
>                  "ScanCode":"015",
>                  "ScanType":"UD",
>                  "ScanGroupType":"S",
>                  "ScanDate":"17-Aug-2017",
>                  "ScanTime":"20:11",
>                  "ScannedLocation":"ULSOOR",
>                  "ScannedLocationCode":"ULS"
>               },
>               {
>                  "Scan":"SHIPMENT ARRIVED",
>                  "ScanCode":"001",
>                  "ScanType":"UD",
>                  "ScanGroupType":"S",
>                  "ScanDate":"17-Aug-2017",
>                  "ScanTime":"19:44",
>                  "ScannedLocation":"ULSOOR MINI HUB",
>                  "ScannedLocationCode":"UMH"
>               }
>            ]
>         }    } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read the text with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) then select the element you need.

ex:

```
$json = json_decode($text, true);
$json['Shipment']['Scans']['ScanDetail'][0]['Scan']; //Your key is here.
```

You can find specific selectors with this site http://jsonselector.com/